# How to render a column n datetime format from AzureML Dataset?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have registered a dataset after an Azure Databricks ETL operation. When it is registered as an AzureML Dataset, one of the columns is rendered as a timestamp. I know the schema has been inferred properly as the Dataset->Explore blade renders it properly:
[image: Dataset_in_Explore_Tab]

However, when using  `Dataset.get_by_name(ws,<name>).to_pandas_dataframe()`, the timestamp column is rendered as all None:

[image: Pandas_Dataframe]

How do I mention the schema so that it is rendered properly while Getting the `Dataset.get_by_name()`

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be a bug, but my guess is that the Explore tab is only looking at the first 1000 rows, which have no issues, but that there may be a malformatted value in a row after the 1st 1000.

Can you:

- confirm the column complete for all rows in Databricks?
- what is the source file format?
- what is the column type for that column in the registered Tabular Dataset, can you confirm that it isn't a string?

Comment: 1. Yes all the rows are complete. Saving in Unix format and converting works.
2. Save using Spark CSV and move the CSV
3. It is Timestamp